# Jquery Mobile- Footer elements, 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a text input and button side by side into a footer, which works fine but i need its width to be 100% i.e Fluid layout. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
       <div style="float:left;">
          <input style="" data-mini="true" type="text" name="message" id="message" value="" data-theme="a"/>
       </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" data-mini="true" data-theme="a"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your form elements inside a grid to automatically stretch the inputs like so:

Supplied my own inline-widths to the inputs to stretch them the way i want. You can also create your own class and use that in conjunction with the `.ui-block-*` class.

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" class="ui-grid-a">
    <div style="width:80%;" class="ui-block-a"><input style="" data-mini="true" type="text" name="message" id="message" value="" data-theme="a"/></div>
    <div style="width:20%;" class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" data-mini="true" data-theme="a"/></div>       
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tKcMg/1/

Comment: That was my first thought but i would like the input to span like 80% and the button 20%.

Comment: @jacksonpollocks you can modify the width of the grids inline or just create your class with the desired width. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tKcMg/1/

Comment: Nice one, i don't know why i never thought of that. I really need to stop having joints for breakfast :D Thanks...

Comment: @jacksonpollocks Awesome, i'll update the answer with the extra bit of code i added and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="resize">
    <input id="text" type="text" style="float:left;"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" style="float:left;" />
</div>

$(function() { 
    resize_input();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        resize_input();
    })
});
function resize_input(){
    var foo = $('div#resize').outerWidth();
    var bar = $('input#submit').outerWidth();
    $('input#text').outerWidth( foo - bar ); 
}
```